# JAVA_HOME does not show all installed JDKs on macOS v12.1

Tags: homebrew, java-home

Trying to install Java11. Looked at existing JDKs using `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` and it returned only one Matching Java Virtual Machine `1.8.0_292 (x86_64)`. Checked with Homebrew using `brew search Java` and discovered Java11 is already installed at `/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk@11`. Why won't JAVA_HOME recognise this? How to make Java11 the default Java instead of the 1.8.0_292?